# Unable to ping host or internet from a multi-linked(bridge + veth interfaces) Linux network namespaces

Tags: networking, docker, network-bridge, virtualbox-networking

I am working on mocking a small enterprise type network using linux network namespaces.
The setup contains a router, bridge, and end user's device. I have configured the setup using the following instructions:

1. Create 2 namespaces `ns1` for the bridge, and `ns2` for the end device.

```
sudo ip netns add ns1
sudo ip netns add ns2
```

2. Create a bridge interface in the default namespace

```
sudo ip link add nsd-br type bridge
sudo ip address add 10.0.0.1/24 dev nsd-br
```

3. Create a veth pair to connect bridge `nsd-br` in the default namespace to namespace `ns1`

```
sudo ip link add ns1-veth0 type veth peer name nsd-veth0
sudo ip link set ns1-veth0 netns ns1
sudo ip link set dev nsd-veth0 master nsd-br
```

4. Create a bridge `ns1-br` in namespace `ns1`

```
sudo ip netns exec ns1 ip link add ns1-br type bridge
sudo ip netns exec ns1 ip address add 10.0.1.1/24 dev ns1-br
```

5. Connect `ns1-br` and `ns2` using veth

```
sudo ip link add ns2-veth1 type veth peer name ns1-veth1
sudo ip link set ns1-veth1 netns ns1
sudo ip link set ns2-veth1 netns ns2
```

6. Set 'ns1-br`as master for`ns1-veth1`

```
sudo ip netns exec ns1 ip link set dev ns1-veth1 master ns1-br
```

7. Configure IP address for `ns2-veth1` in namespace `ns2`

```
sudo ip netns exec ns2 ip address add 10.0.1.2/24 dev ns2-veth1
```

8. Turn on all the interfaces:

```
sudo ip link set dev nsd-br up
sudo ip link set dev nsd-veth0 up
sudo ip netns exec ns1 ip link set dev ns1-br up
sudo ip netns exec ns1 ip link set dev ns1-veth0 up
sudo ip netns exec ns1 ip link set dev ns1-veth1 up
sudo ip netns exec ns2 ip link set dev ns2-veth1 up
```

9. Setup routing for all namespaces

```
sudo ip route add 10.0.0.1/24 via 10.0.0.1 dev nsd-br (automatically configured by kernel)
sudo ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.1 dev nsd-br

# for ns1
sudo ip netns exec ns1 ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.4 dev ns1-veth0 (automatically configured by kernel)
sudo ip netns exec ns1 ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.1.1 dev ns1-br

# for ns2

sudo ip netns exec ns2 ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.1.1 dev ns2-veth1 (automatically configured by kernel)
sudo ip netns exec ns2 ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 via 10.0.1.1 dev ns2-veth1
```

[The setup looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADoqe.png)

#### Problem

1. I am not able to ping `10.0.0.1` (nsd-br) from `ns2`, and not able to ping `10.0.1.2` from the default namespace.
2. I am not able to ping internet(1.1.1.1) from `ns2`

When I am pinging `10.0.1.2` from the default namespace, the tcpdump output of the interfaces `nsd-br`, `ns1-veth0`:

```
10:04:37.576618 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.1.2 tell 10.0.0.1, length 28
```

but the interface `ns1-br` is not getting these packets.

The MAC address of `10.0.1.2` is not present on interface `ns1-veth0` but is present on `ns1-br`, why are the ARP tables not shared between the interfaces if both interfaces are on the same namespace?

Also, there are no NAT rules, and all traffic is forwarded by default in namespaces `ns1` and `ns2`.